# IONIC 4 FILE PLUGIN : resolveLocalFilesystemUrl resolves but gives every value as "UNDEFIED" of the "entry object"

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have been trying to read text file content stored in native device(ANDROID/IoS)
Here's the code

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n0OS.png)

I am using capacitor and native-plugin :FILE

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\chawd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0
```

Capacitor:

```
   Capacitor CLI   : 2.0.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.0.0
```

Cordova:

```
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)
```

Utility:

```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.0.0
```

System:

```
   NodeJS : v12.16.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Basically, to find out the error as i couldn't find online anywhere, i started digging into the code, and what i noticed was, `readAsText(...)` internally calls `resolveLocalFileSystemURL(...)` function in the path of execution, but `resolveLocalFileSystemURL(...)` gives every value of entry object as `'undefined'`,
i did play with the code but couldn't do much, so here i am to seek help :)

Comment: Why not use [Capacitor's FileSystem](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem) API?

Comment: Tried but it also has a bug, whether i read or write, it shows "parent folder doesn't exist" on android